# How to add dynamic text in ng-model name

Tags: html, angularjs, ngmodel

Is it possible to add dynamic text in the `ng-model` name?

**data js**

```
self.Map = [{ Id: 0, Name: 'Map1' }, { Id: 1, Name: 'Map2' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Map3' }]
```

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="option in mainCtrl.Map">
    <div style="text-align:left;" class="col-md-6">
        {{option.Name}} Map
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:right;" class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" id="Is{{option.Name}}" name="Is{{option.Name}}" ng-model="mainCtrl.Is{{option.Name}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**desired output**

```
ng-model="mainCtrl.IsMap1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp, you can access object in these 2 way:

```
objectName.propertyName

objectName["propertyName"]
```

You may try following way such that angularJs can bind the value you want:

```
<input type="text" id="Is{{option.Name}}" name="Is{{option.Name}}" ng-model="mainCtrl['Is'+option.Name]"/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `ng-model="mainCtrl['Is'+option.Name]"` works for me but for some reason it doesn't work this way `ng-model="mainCtrl[option.Name+'Role']"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add dummy field to your HTML input tag like

```
<div ng-repeat="option in mainCtrl.Map">
    <div style="text-align:left;" class="col-md-6">
        {{option.Name}} Map
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:right;" class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" id="Is{{option.Name}}" name="Is{{option.Name}}" ng-model="mainCtrl[this.getAttribute('dummyfield')]" dummyfield="{{option.Name}}Role" />
    </div>
</div>
```